# Podman: Send Message to Listener in Container

Tags: podman

I'm running a centos 7 dotnet 6.0 container with a dotnet listener service running in it. It's listening on "http://localhost:5000". I have Podman 1.6.4 installed. Can anyone advise me on how to send messages from the host to the listener in the container?

Comment: If the service is listening on `localhost` then you cannot send any messages to it from anywhere. You need to ensure that the service listens on all addresses (`0.0.0.0`) (after which the answer depends on how exactly you've started the container and from where you're trying to connect to it).

Comment: When I run the service it displays "Now listening on: http://localhost:5000". I'm guessing that's the default, as it's not explicitly defined in the code nor json file.
As for how I'm tring to connect: I'm using Netcat ("nc IPAddress 5000").

Comment: If you want to show us the code you're running we can take a look, but otherwise there simply isn't enough information here for us to answer the question.